Move multiple lines of code using alt + arrow up/down
how to fix visual studio code can't move multiple lines of code using alt + arrow up/down?
When i was tried to move multiple lines of code up or down using the keyboard shortcut alt + up or alt + down it won't move the multiple lines of code that i've selected.
I've never change my key bindings on Visual Studio Code. And when i search for some tutorials, all the tutorials said that it must be ctrl+ up/down to move a single line of code or multiple lines. Any solution?

Can you provide more information? For example, is it a fresh install?, or did it previously work and has now stopped working?
What version do you use? Also, did you check the current shortcut on the settings?
Settings > Keyboard shortcuts: keyboard shortcuts

I recently re - install the Vscode and currently i'm using the 1.91.0 version of VScode, I already check and re - check the keyboard shortcuts including the keybindings.json but it's still didnt't work. before the update it was all fine.

Works fine for me.  Try Reload with Extensions Disabled command to see if it makes any difference.

I have found the solution, so it was actually me who forgot to highlighted the block of code first using the command ctrl + shift + arrow up/down then I can move the selected block of code. I thought that we have to put the multiple cursor in the multiple line / block of code that we want to move without highlighted the code. But turns out, we must highlight the block of code first then we can move it :')
